# Block zoom in HTA

Tags: zooming, hta

I have an HTA that has this structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--head elements-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <!--toolbar elements-->
        </div>
        <div id="mainframe">
            <!--main frame elements-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I zoom (for example by holding the CTRL key down and scrolling), it changes the zoom in the whole document, including in the toolbar. I want it to only zoom in the main frame, and always leave the toolbar at 100% zoom. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You've to listen the mouse wheel event, and change the zoom level of the main frame in the handler. Changing the behavior of CTRL+wheel is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<body onmousewheel="javascript:if(window.event.ctrlKey){return false}">
```